# how to print the list of strings from the xml tags

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, xbmc

I'm working on my python script to print the list of strings from my own xml file.

I'm trying to find out how to print the list of strings from the programme-channel tag to get the format in the start="" and stop="" tags. When I'm trying to get the list of format and the title, I will only get the list of channels which you can see it here:

```
0115:00:58 T:3316  NOTICE: 101 ABC FAMILY
0215:00:58 T:3316  NOTICE: 102 CBS
0315:00:58 T:3316  NOTICE: 103 CNN USA
0415:00:58 T:3316  NOTICE: 105 ESPN USA
0515:00:58 T:3316  NOTICE: 106 Fox News
0615:00:58 T:3316  NOTICE: 107 Animal Planet
0715:00:58 T:3316  NOTICE: 108 USA Network
0815:00:58 T:3316  NOTICE: 110 SPIKE
0915:00:58 T:3316  NOTICE: 111 BRAVO USA
1015:00:58 T:3316  NOTICE: 112 BRAVO1
1115:00:58 T:3316  NOTICE: 113 BRAVO2
1215:00:58 T:3316  NOTICE: 114 BRAVO3
1315:00:58 T:3316  NOTICE: 115 BRAVO4
1415:00:58 T:3316  NOTICE: 116 BRAVO5
1515:00:58 T:3316  NOTICE: 117 BRAVO6
1615:00:58 T:3316  NOTICE: 118 BRAVO7
```

Here is the xml:

```
<tv generator-info-name="www.mysite.com/xmltv">
<channel id="101 ABC FAMILY">
<display-name>101 ABC FAMILY</display-name>
<programme channel="101 ABC FAMILY" start="" stop="20140517070000">
<title lang="en">The Karate Kid Part III</title>
<sub-title lang="en"></sub-title>
<desc lang="en"></desc>
<category lang="en"></category>
</programme>
<programme channel="101 ABC FAMILY"start="20140517070000" stop="20140517093000">
<title lang="en">The Karate Kid</title>
<sub-title lang="en"></sub-title>
<desc lang="en"></desc>
<category lang="en"></category>
</programme>
</channel>
```

Here is the code:

```
#DOWNLOAD THE XML SOURCE HERE
url = ADDON.getSetting('allchannels.url')
req = urllib2.Request(url)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
data = response.read()
response.close()
profilePath =xbmc.translatePath(os.path.join('
special://userdata/addon_data/script.tvguide', ''))

if os.path.exists(profilePath):
  profilePath = profilePath + 'source.db'
  con = database.connect(profilePath)
  cur = con.cursor()
  cur.execute('CREATE TABLE programs(id TEXT, channel TEXT, title TEXT, 
start_date TIMESTAMP, end_date TIMESTAMP, description TEXT)')
  con.commit()
  con.close
  tv_elem =ElementTree.parse(StringIO.StringIO(data)).getroot()

  profilePath =xbmc.translatePath(os.path.join('special://userdata/addon_data/script.tvguide', ''))
  profilePath = profilePath + 'source.db'
  con = database.connect(profilePath)
  cur = con.cursor()
  channels = OrderedDict()

  for elem in tv_elem.getchildren():
    if elem.tag == 'channel':
       channels[elem.attrib['id']] =self.load_channel(elem)
    elif elem.tag == 'programme':
       # get channel
       channel =channels[elem.attrib['programme']]
       channel =channels[elem.attrib['title']]
       # load program in channel
       channel.get_programs().append(self.load_programme(elem))
       for channel_key in channels:
         channel = channels[channel_key]
         display_name =channel.get_display_name()
         print channel.get_display_name()
```

Can you please help me how i can print the list of format from the start="" and stop="" tags as well from the title tag?

Comment: What does print the list of format mean? What output are you expecting? PS Have you heard of the design principle, a function should do one thing?

Comment: @TonyHopkinson I mean the format like 20140517000000 which 2014 is the year, 05 is the month, 17 is the date and the 00 is the hours, mins and seconds. I'm trying to get the format in the start="" and stop="" which i have only print the list of channels. Can you please help me how to print the format in the start="" and stop="" tags??

Comment: @TonyHopkinson any idea how i can print the format in the start="" and stop""??

Comment: If you convert a datetime to that format, then one google and one link and you get strftime. https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior

Comment: @TonyHopkinson I'm using PHP to convert the time into format. so how I can get the format in the start="" and stop="" tags using python to print the format? how i can do that?

Comment: Huh Where did PHP come come from? I believe we are having a major difficulty in understanding each other.